# Extract user specified sequence from reverse strand of from FASTA file Using samtools

Tags: samtools

I have a list of regions with start and end points.

I used the `samtools faidx ref.fa <region>` command. This command gave me the forward strand sequence for that region.

In the samtools manual there is an option to extract reverse strand but I could not figure out how to use that.

Does anybody know how to run this command for reverse strand in samtools?

My regions are like:

```
 LG2:124522-124572 (Forward)
 LG3:250022-250072 (Reverse)
 LG29:4822278-4822318 (Reverse)
 LG12:2,595,915-2,596,240 (Forward)
 LG16:5,405,500-5,405,828 (Reverse)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, `samtools` has the option `--reverse-complement` (or `-i`) to output the sequence from the reverse strand.

As far as I know, `samtools` does not support a region notation which permits specifying the strand.

A quick solution would be to separate your region file into forward and reverse locations and run `samtools` twice.

The steps below are rather verbose, just so the steps are clear. It's fairly straight-forward to clean this up with process substitution in bash, for example.

```
# Separate the strand regions.

# Use grep and sed twice, or awk (below).
grep -F '(Forward)' regions.txt | sed 's/ (Forward)//' > forward-regions.txt
grep -F '(Reverse)' regions.txt | sed 's/ (Reverse)//' > reverse-regions.txt

# Above as an awk one-liner.
awk '{ strand=($2 == "(Forward)") ? "forward" : "reverse"; print $1 > strand"-regions.txt" }' regions.txt

# Run samtools, marking the strand as +/- in the FASTA output.
samtools faidx ref.fa -r forward-regions.txt --mark-strand sign -o forward-sequences.fa 
samtools faidx ref.fa -r reverse-regions.txt --mark-strand sign -o reverse-sequences.fa --reverse-complement

# Combine the FASTA output to a single file.
cat forward-sequences.fa reverse-sequences.fa > sequences.fa
rm forward-sequences.fa reverse-sequences.fa
```

Answer (score 0):

just want to mention that you probably need to update your samtools to the latest version if you met problem. In my case, samtools V1.2 didn't work, and V1.10 worked.